# how to store object in array where i want to declare 2 or more object and how to call that array using anther class object

Tags: java, arrays

this is main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Author[] authors=new Author[2];
        for(int i=0;i<=authors.length;i++);
        authors[0]=new Author("suru","suru@qwe.com","m");
        authors[1]=new Author("aksh","aksh@qwe.com","m");
        for(int i=0;i<=authors.length;i++);
        System.out.println(authors);

        Book book=new Book("java",authors,200,2);
        System.out.println(book);
```

now i created 2nd class authoer with getter and setter

```
private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;

    public Author (String name,String email, String gender) 
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.gender=gender;

    }
```

noow i created new class Book

```
public class Book {
private String name;
private Author[] author;
private double price;
private int qty=0;

public Book(String name,Author[] author,double price, int qty) {
    this.name=name;
    this.author=author;
    this.price=price;
    this.qty=qty;
    }
```

when i run this program the output give the memory adress ho can i print theese detail

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `toString()` method in the class `Author`.
For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Author [name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
}
```

Comment: i already override toSting method but code is not run public String toString() {
  return name+   "  "   +email+   "  "  +gender+  "  ";

Answer (score 2):

When you pass as argument of the method `System.out.println()` name of variable, method `toString()` of the class of that variable is being called. If you don't override that method in class `Author` or `Book`, `toString()` method inherited by these classes from `Object` class is being called (all classes in Java inherit from `Object` class). By default, this method prints address in memory for classes with `toString()` not defined in their bodies. There is a simple example, how you can override it in `Author` method:

```
class Author {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Author name: " + this.name + "\nAuthor email: " + this.email + "\nAuthor gender : " + this.gender;
}
```

To print contents of an array (in your example to print each `Author` contained in `Author[] authors`) you might want to use one of these way to achieve that (as `Author[]` or `Book[]` is actually a type of array and not a type of `Book` or `Author` and has its own `toString()` method printing address in memory) :

1. Create a loop iterating over each element of `authors` array:

   ```
   for (Author author : authors) {
       System.out.println(author + "------"); // toString() method of each Author is called and added simple separator
   }
   ```
2. Call `Arrays.toString(authors)` method. Class `Arrays` is provided to let you manipulate arrays in many different ways. You can read about this class in Java API documentation. This is a part of what documentation says about `Arrays.toString()` method:

   *Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.*

Comment: @akshayshete what does it mean? What error do you get?

Comment: it gives java [Loops.Author;@1db9742 200.0 2  this output

Comment: @akshayshete I edited my answer to let you now that you should print arrays in a different way :-) I forgot to mention it in my first attempt

Answer (score 0):

```
    package oops;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Author[] authors=new Author[2];
        for(int i=0;i<=authors.length;i++);
        authors[0]=new Author("suru","suru@qwe.com","m");
        authors[1]=new Author("aksh","aksh@qwe.com","m");
        for(int i=0;i<=authors.length;i++);
        System.out.println(authors);

        Book book=new Book("java",authors,200,2);
        System.out.println(book);

    }

}

    package oops;

public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;

    public Author (String name,String email, String gender) 
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.gender=gender;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name+   "  "   +email+   "  "  +gender+  "  ";

    }


    package oops;

public class Book {
private String name;
private Author[] author;
private double price;
private int qty=0;

public Book(String name,Author[] author,double price, int qty) {
    this.name=name;
    this.author=author;
    this.price=price;
    this.qty=qty;
    }
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}
public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}
public  String getName() {
    return name;

}
/*public Author[] getAuthor() {
    return author;

} */
public Author[] getAuther() {
     for (int i=0;i<=author.length;i++);
    return author;
}

 public String toString() {
    return name+" "+author+" "+price+" "+qty+" ";

 }
 public Author[] getAutherNames() {
     for (int i=0;i<=author.length;i++);
    return author;
 }
}
```

this is my full program

Comment: Don't post this code in answers section, edit your question and include part causing problems there (not the whole code, as it is unnecessary). As I read it, I strongly suggest you to take some time a learn about how to build for-loop, how to use return key-word and how to use array indexes as for now your code is really full of errors...

Answer (score 0):

You an override toString() or you can print the attributes of the object directly as follows:

```
Book b = new Book(/*args*/);
System.out.println("Name: " + b.name);
// continue printing all the attributes in the same way
```

You can try this instead of overriding toString() method in the object class.
Hope this helps...